# Swift POST JSON return 500

Tags: json, post, swift2

I have a problem with my POST, it returns 500 as a response.

Here is my code:

```
let postParams: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["user_id": user_id, "prayer": [["user_id":data["user_id"], "prayer_date":data["prayer_date"], "name":data["name"]]]]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postParams, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        } catch {
            print("bad things happened")
        }
        print(request.HTTPBody)
        // Make the POST call and handle it in a completion handler
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // Make sure we get an OK response
            guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("Not a 200 response")
                print(response)
                return
            }

            // Read the JSON
            if let postString = NSString(data:data! , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
                // Print what we got from the call
                let dictionary = self.JSONParseDictionary(postString)

                let status = (dictionary as NSDictionary)["status"] as! Bool
                print(status)
            }

        }).resume()
```

From the API's it requires `user_id` as `int` and `prayer` as an array.

Comment: HTTP 500 = Internal server error. The *server* has an issue when it receives this request.

Comment: thanks eric, but do you know how to fix it? because when i sending the data like {"user_id":"1", "prayer":"something"} that working fine
and my problem is when i sending the data like this {"user_id":"1", "prayer":[array]}

Comment: Fix your *server*.

Comment: thanks for your help, it was from my server, so i fix my server